# Is it possible to open a Text File in Pascal several times in the same program?

Tags: text-files, pascal

I am trying to make a program that allow me to read a text file and then print it in the terminal.

I just put the simplified parts below so that you see how I think it should work.

My problem is that if for example I open the file a.txt then b.txt it works.
But when I want to open a.txt again, the program stops with an error 217. Same if I want to open another file name c.txt for example. I've spent days on this problem but I do not know where it comes from. I looked on the internet and erorr 217 seems to be related to a non-existing file ? but it is not the case for me...

The error seems to occur on the 'assign' function.

To clarify :

'key' is a Char,

'map' is a two dimension dynamic array of a Record Type.

```
Repeat
     readln(key);
     name := key +'.txt';
     fileLoading(name, map, maxX, maxY);
Until key = 'l';
```

...

```
procedure fileLoading (name : String; var map : PPObjet; var maxX,maxY : Integer);
var
    fichier : Text;
    i, j : Integer;
    chaine : String;

begin
    
    if (FileExists(name)) then
    begin
        assign(fichier, name);
        reset(fichier);
        read(fichier,maxX);
        readln(fichier,maxY);
        if (maxX < 1) or (maxX > MAX) or (maxY < 1) or (maxY > MAX) then
        begin
            writeln('Tailles invalides');
            halt();
        end;
            
        allocationTab(maxX, maxY, map);
        while (not eof(fichier)) do
        begin
            for j := 1 to maxY do
            begin
                readln(fichier,chaine);
                for i := 1 to maxX do
                begin
                    case chaine[i] of 
                    '0'     :   begin
                                    map[j][i].solide := false;
                                    map[j][i].nature := 'v';
                                    map[j][i].valeur := chaine[i];
                                end;
                    '1'     :   begin
                                    map[j][i].solide := true;
                                    map[j][i].nature := 'm';
                                    map[j][i].valeur := chaine[i];
                                end;
                    '2'..'9' :  begin
                                    map[j][i].solide := false;
                                    map[j][i].nature := 's';
                                    map[j][i].valeur := chaine[i];
                                end;
                        
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
        writeln('Erreur le fichier n''existe pas');
        halt();
    end;
    close(fichier);
end;
```

...

This is the first time I ask a question on stack overflow and I'm not really familiar with it, so I hope my problem is clear enough, as well as my english.
Thanks in advance for all the help you may bring.

Comment: Are you aware that dynamic arrays use 0-based indexing?

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
 filemode:=0;
```

before your assign/reset

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work.